# Alternative to find?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, find, utilities

Is there an alternative `find` program with a more conventional CLI interface? `find` works and expects parameters in a painfully different way from most other utils.

Clarification: I'm looking for a program that has mostly the same functionality as find with a commandline interface that works and feels like POSIX (or at least GNU) commandline recommendations.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'more conventional', here... Perhaps you can clarify your question?

Comment: GNU find does not respect POSIX (or even GNU) guidelines for command line. For example, ordering of parameters, multi-character options with a single dash etc. are different than in conforming programs.

Comment: @Tamas, I agree that find's parameters are backwards, but they work... and you really don't need them in the majority of cases, you can hack things up by piping into grep which has a more sensible syntax

Comment: I know, and I can always do what I intend, one way or another. I just recently got to know `ack` and was wondering if there is a better `find` as well.

Comment: Find is a powerful tool, nearly a small language, where the ordering of parameters matters - while it doesn't matter for most programs, so they don't have to solve such problems. Can you suggest a better way to handle the options without losing functionality?

Comment: No. You see, I don't want a small programming language, but a simpler, more intuitive and more consistent find (even if that means the loss of some advanced functionality). When I face a task that justifies writing a program, I do.

Comment: find is both consistent (see my answer) and intuitive. It's not like primaries are named weird. -exec means execute, -print means print it, -name means match a name. In practice, the former 3 and -type cover 95% of the usage cases. For all other cases, there's man find.

Comment: Ok @Mel, you are right. But neither this comment nor your answer actually answer my question.

Comment: @tamas I edited an hour ago and told you there's no alternative except locate. And maybe ls -R come to think of it. Other alternatives are GUI programs that emulate find. Otherwise you have to specify what you want your find alternative to do. Walk dir trees? Filter file names? Tell you which files is newer then?

Comment: What do you want it to do?  What should the syntax look like?

Comment: Maybe he wants single character options like -e -n -p for -exec, -name and -print, or double dashes, like --exec, --name and --print? @Tamás Szelei: What should be dropped to make your life more easy?

Comment: This seems to have been bumped by Community, so I am late to the party, but in all seriousness try to define *what you would like* in moderate detail. You are probably not the only one interested because `find` does have one of the more esoteric and difficult command line interfaces in unix. But you may find that you end up with either something quite limited in comparison to the existing tool or something equally as complicated. If you get a good definition, write it down; someone might be willing to help implement it.

Comment: @Mel you are correct that `find` is consistent; I am hard-pressed to find it "intuitive." For instance, it shouldn't be nearly this difficult to figure out how to prune branches of the directory tree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command  (Note the disparities between the top three (!) answers.)

Comment: Great question, poor answers, and even worse comments. I like how they're trying to convince you that no, really, you want to use find, even though you hate it.

Comment: @Pod what's really missing from this question is clarification of the types of metadata that the OP wants to be able to search for. For example, if it's only names then there are several alternative tools that spring to mind (including the `*locate` family). If it's names and dates then one needs to define the relationship between name and date (both must match? either must match? neither must match?). After that it starts to get complicated. But without an understanding of what the OP is hoping for it's difficult to provide a useful tool.

Comment: @Pod  (And yes, I know I'm also late to the party, but the question's not yet been tagged as answered, and it is a fair question.)

Comment: It's a shame that I cannot add a constructive answer. So let this comment suffice: take a look at https://github.com/sharkdp/fd (Debian package `fd-find`), it might be just what you are looking for. It certainly does the job for me and I find it much easier to use than `find`.

Answer (score 13):

I would take a look at `locate`. It will look through its database of files and quickly print out path names that match what you give.

```
kevin@box:~$ locate odg
/home/kevin/Documents/final.odg
/usr/share/doc/packages/sysconfig/netconfig.odg
/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/gimp-tool-dodge-burn.html
....
kevin@box:~$ locate .odg
/home/kevin/Documents/final.odg
/usr/share/doc/packages/sysconfig/netconfig.odg
kevin@box:~$
```

As you can see, it is a sub-text match: if you give it `odg`, then it will match d**odg**e. But if you give it `.odg`, then it won't.

There is one downside, though: it needs a database. This database needs to be updated when things change. My Fedora 13 install has this put into a daily crontab, though.

Comment: I love `locate`

Comment: Moreover, locate also accepts patterns (I learned this just recently).

Answer (score 11):

This is a common misconception.

Find follows the options syntax. You're just confusing expression primaries with options:

```
 find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
 [cmd][-->        options          <--] [--> arg0..argN  <--]
```

The alternative is locate. But find implements its own expression syntax because it provides a richer set of filter and action options. There's no alternative that can do the same, simply because it would be redundant.

Comment: What is the difference between expression (only one allowed?), cmd (dito?), options and args?

Comment: @user unknown -- the find command implements it's own expression syntax. The expression, when given, is the last argument on the command line. When absent, expression resolves to -print.

Comment: Ah - now I see, [cmd] isn't following [expression], but it's a description of the line before.

Comment: OP asserts that `find` "expects parameters in a painfully different way from most other utils". You state that OP is "confusing expression primaries with options". Do most other utils even have a concept of "expression primaries"? If not, doesn't that *demonstrate* OP's point? And that's really not the strangest part of using `find`. What other CLI involves `{}` (which of course must be escaped somehow)?

Comment: I hope someone makes a modern tool, like the way `mc` makes `ls` seem outdated, and `ncdu` makes `du` seem outdated, and `zsh` / `fish` makes `bash` seem outdated. I want an `nclocate .` which makes `locate` operate on a path with autocomplete in realtime, like google does for websites, or Ctrl-F does in `nautilus` GUI

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the precise functionality of `find` that you are relying on.  If it is (principally) the finding functionality, some shells support recursive globs. E.g., with `zsh`:

```
% find . -name \*c
./a/b/foo.c
./a/bar.c
./baz.c
inoshiro% ls *.c
baz.c
% ls **/*.c 
a/bar.c  a/b/foo.c  baz.c
```

Zsh has a lot more find-like possibilities through [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (look near the end of `man zshexpn`). For example:

`ls -l **/*(.)`  ≈  `find -type f -ls`
`ls *(m-2u:$USER:)`  ≈  `find -mtime -2 -user $USER`

Bash 4 also has `**/` (you need to enable it with `shopt -s globstar`), but nothing like glob qualifiers.

Answer (score 6):

What are you trying to find?  If you're typically searching for source code files, take a look at [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com).  It's basically a source code search tool, but ack's `-f` switch will find files that match a given filetype.

So if you want to find all the Perl files in a directory, for example, just:

```
ack -f --perl
```

If you don't like the filetypes that ack recognizes, you can add your own in your `~/.ackrc`.

ack is not a general-purpose file finder like `find`, but if you're working with source code, it can be very handy.

Comment: This is not what user asked but people might find very useful for find in source code (like grep) [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), `silversearcher-ag` package on main distros.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things every programmer should learn is: If you can't find a tool, build your own!

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
find -name $<
```

I might write a better one, with `-t` to filter types, etc.

**Edit**: The above is a Bash script. It takes the command line argument and passes it to find as the -name option's value. Just a simple example.
Since I put up this answer, I found this python script:

https://github.com/sjl/friendly-find/

The interface looks nice, but I haven't tested its performance. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: True for building own tool statement. But at least explain how your little script is supposed to work.

Comment: `$<` is not doing anything useful in my Bash.  What do you expect it to do?  Do you mean `"$@"` actually?  Or `"$1"` (which is basically what this means in a Makefile)?

Comment: @tripleee - `$<` is the `csh` equivalent of `read` - I'm guessing he meant that.

Answer (score 0):

Most standard way to find things in unix's.

```
du -a <directory>|grep <pattern>| awk  '{print $2}'
```

Comment: `grep | awk` is an antipattern.  See [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).  If you want to parametrize the pattern, maybe `du -a | awk -v "pat=<pattern>" '$0 ~ pat { print $2 }'`

Comment: @tripleee That's very helpful info about `awk`, but one of the great advantages of the UNIX philosophy is that one doesn't need to understand all the features of the more complex tools (such as `awk` and `find`) in order to construct pipelines that can perform the desired task. `grep | awk` may not be optimal (or, on a performant multithreaded system with a highly optimized `grep`, maybe it would be!), but it's *simple*.

Comment: it works. It cannot be downvoted if it works as a solution, Can be improved though.